# Not able to update Playstore Listing

Tags: android

Trying to update store listing but not able to, not able to find what's wrong with the build we haven't added anything extra in manifest file from last 3 months.

[image: Not able to figure out what exactly have to do]
[image: Release Tab gives this warning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested by Google play support team

Remove All Drafted Artifacts from the Developer console and then wait for 2 - 3 Hrs.

If your  still not able to contact [Google Console support team](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en#contact=1)

After contacting support team issue resolved in 24 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to update my Alpha and Beta builds as well.
Got the idea from Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/at0reb/app_removed_from_play_store_for_smscall_log/egxyr84/